# Calculating the total elements unique to each data

Tags: sql

Here's the situation. I created a view that has all the following information

```
CREATE VIEW view2 AS
SELECT activity_id,
       subject_code,
       academic_period_code,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR,time_start,time_end) AS duration
FROM   activity
```

Okay, now I'm trying to make a query that can produce two columns, 
1. one with subject code and the academic_period code concatenated into one column
2. The second column contains the total number of duration for each subject that is in that academic period

So its like: CS123 in academic_period 121 has total of 5 hours activity. I'm fine with the first column but I've been wondering how do I get the 2nd column. If I use the SUM function it just totals up the column itself so I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Sample data

```
Subject Code   Activity_code    Academic_Period_Code   Duration
CS123          1                 121                   2
CS123          2                 121                   3
CS123          3                 122                   2
CS123          4                 122                   2
```

What I have done?]

```
SELECT subject_code + academic_period_code AS subject,
       (I think I have to do a subquery but I'm not sure how its suppose to work out) AS total_activity_time
```

FROM view2

Comment: To help others help you, add to your question some sample data (one record is enough) and your expected results. And, obviously, what have you already tried to achieve this concatenation.

Comment: Jeremy's group by should give you the total your looking for.  Check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server and that I understand what you are looking for:

```
select
    subject_code + academic_period_code as [Type],
    sum(duration) as duration
from view2
group by
    subject_code + academic_period_code;
```

should get you where I think you're trying to get.

Comment: I deleted my answer after you said I had the wrong columns... but I gotta ask.  Where are you getting academic_id ?  Question asked to concat subject_code and academic_period_code.

Comment: Okay, I get concatenating it. But I have no idea how to get the data to sum up the total_activity_time

Comment: @RThomas ... !!! Whups!  Yeah I'm an idiot.  The reason you had the wrong columns was different though... you were going off the main table instead of the view, where the datetime was not calculated.

Comment: yeah the time duration is already calculated. I just cant seem to get the total of the duration thats unique to each academic period and also the subject

Comment: @Jeremy Ahhh, finally saw what you were taking about.  So I was.  Other than that our answers were nearly identical so I'll leave it deleted.

Comment: @nfnmy, the `group by` clause should clarify your aggregate `sum` function.  If I understand what you're trying to do, this should be exactly what you need.

Comment: works like a charm..at first I was receiving errors but it was because the GROUP BY didn't match the data I was concatenating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    subject_code + academic_period_code as subjects,
    sum(duration) as duration
from view2
group by
    subject_code, academic_period_code;
```